# Flutter android app crash on Android App Bundle build

Tags: android, flutter, proguard, android-app-bundle

I have made an application using `flutter`. It is working fine as `debug` build also `release .apk` build working fine. Release .apk build size for the app is `65 MB`. However, as now it is mandatory to submit `.aab` in play console i created the `.aab` release and submitted the app in `Internal Test Track`. Now when i try to install it from internal test track the installation size becomes `22 MB` and after installing i can't even open the app as it crashes while opening. My `build.gradle` is as follows

```
...
buildTypes{
   release{
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
}
...
```

**Note: I have proper proguard rules for each plugin i used**

At this point when it was not working i decided not to use shrinking so i disabled code/resource shrinking by doing following in `build.gradle` file

```
...
buildTypes{
   release{
      shrinkResources false
      minifyEnabled false
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
}
...
```

Still no luck. App bundle build size is 65 MB but when i try to install from internal test track it is 22 MB only and app crash while opening.

What can i do in this situation?

**EDIT:**
I got following crash log on `Firebase Crashlytis`

```
Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found

Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(FlutterJNI.java:13)
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:14)
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: Can you build a debug abb file or enable logs in release and check what's the crash to investigate further

Comment: @NitishChaudhary i have added the crash log that i received in firebase crashlutics. Please check.

Comment: Can you try adding ndk filters in build.gradle . I'm not sure what's the reason for crash here but I faced the similar issue in android and was due to library code missing in 64-bit module
 release {
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64'
            }
        }

Comment: @NitishChaudhary let me try adding that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to the abiFilters in build.gradle under android/app/build

```
defaultConfig { 
    ndk { 
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a' 
    }
}
```

Documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#gc